# How can I capture frames from X11 into a file?

Tags: linux, x11, framebuffer, screen-capture, avi

I think there should be some sort of internal support on screen capture utilities with X11. So how can I capture frames from X11 frame-buffer into a file, e.g. AVI, JPEG, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these apps:

- http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/vnc2swf/pyvnc2swf.html

If the apps don't work you can look at their source code to see how to do your own app.